# F# Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously only uses one of the eight CPU core?

Tags: f#

I created a dotnet core application and run the following code of release build. However, the total CPU usage of the PC is around only 20% and process `dotnet` run takes only 12% (I have eight logical CPUs and I don't see any one of it use 100% either). Isn't the CPU the bottleneck of the code?

```
open FSharpx.Control

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let ag = new BlockingQueueAgent<int option>(500)

    let enqueue() = async { for i = 0 to 1000 do ag.Add (Some i) }
    async {
        do! [ for i = 0 to 1000 do yield enqueue() ] 
            |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore
        ag.Add None
    } |> Async.Start

    let mutable x = 0

    let rec dequeue() =
        async {
            let! m = ag.AsyncGet()
            match m with
            | Some v ->
                //x <- x ^^^ v
                for z = 0 to 10000 do x <- x + z
                return! dequeue()
            | None -> 
                printfn "Done %d" x
        }

    [ for i = 0 to 100 do yield dequeue() ] 
    |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore |> Async.RunSynchronously
    0
```

Here is the source code of `BlockingQueueAgent`:
https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Async/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Async/BlockingQueueAgent.fs

**Update:**
Added more complex code (repaced `x <- x ^^^ v`). Now it uses a CPU core a lot. Still 13% though. Why it doesn't use multiple core?

[image: CPU6IsUsed]

Comment: Some thoughts. With a blocking queue that has a some kind of semaphore protecting it's access one can imagine that this semaphore prevents multiple cores from executing at the same time especially since it looks the operation is very cheap. In addition; Async isn't really the best abstraction for CPU bound scenarios. Async is meant for IO bound scenarios. Hopac is a better tool for CPU bound scenarios. In addition; the `printfn` introduces IO which can prevent CPU execution.

Comment: The `printfn` will be only called once at the end when all data is processed. The blocking queue is implemented using `MailBoxProcesser`.

Comment: I don't think you're correct to say that the `printfn` will only be called once at the end when all data is processed. It's called in the `dequeue()` function, and you have 101 copies of `dequeue()` running simultaneously at the end of your `main` function. So that's 101 calls to `printfn` running at once, probably queueing for access to the console. Try removing that `printfn "Done %d" x` line and replacing it with `()`, and see if that increases your CPU usage. If so, then the `printfn` line was the bottleneck.

Comment: @rmunn, the `printfn` in `dequeue` function will be called only when `None` is received. `None` is sent once by the `enqueue` at the end after all data is sent.

Comment: @Justanothermetaprogrammer, I tried to change `x <- x ^^^ v` to more CPU expensive code and it still only uses 13%. It seems now it uses a full CPU core now.

Answer (score 4):

You're synchronously enqueueing all of your `Add` operations before you start dequeuing any messages. This means that when the agent is choosing what to do next it will always `Add` a new item to the queue if it isn't full. When it *is* full, it will search for the first `AsyncGet` operation and process that, but then will immediately `Add` (synchronously) the next item to the queue before allowing another message to be dequeued. This effectively only allows you to dequeue one message at a time because the agent is always switching back and forth between `Add` and `AsyncGet` operations.

If you do an `AsyncAdd` instead of an `Add` then both enqueuing and dequeueing can happen asynchronously and you get the desired behaviour, i.e.

```ml
let enqueue() = async { for i = 0 to 1000 do do! ag.AsyncAdd (Some i) }
```

Comment: Thanks. Now CPU usage fluctuates between 50% and 80%. I found omitting the `do!` in your code also gets low CPU usages.